# compare two dates in same column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, biometrics

We have biometric data which contain three column Employee id, TimeIn, and autoincrement id.
We have to find out the employee hours but the employee may be in and out two or three times in a day. 
How to find out the hours for his in and out entry. There is no column in which we say in and out. We also did max(TimeIn) and min(TimeIn) difference. But in our case, it is not possible because of an employee in and out at any time and many times in a day.

```
   13   2017-10-31 23:15:11 1   255 1   0
   13   2017-10-31 23:15:27 1   255 1   0
    3   2017-11-01 05:54:06 1   255 1   0
    2   2017-11-01 05:54:31 1   255 1   0
   11   2017-11-01 05:55:58 1   255 1   0
    1   2017-11-01 05:56:24 1   255 1   0
   14   2017-11-01 06:02:23 1   255 1   0
    8   2017-11-01 07:54:24 1   255 1   0
    8   2017-11-01 07:54:27 1   255 1   0
    7   2017-11-01 08:06:37 1   255 1   0
   13   2017-11-01 08:29:52 1   255 1   0
   10   2017-11-01 09:54:41 1   255 1   0
   15   2017-11-01 10:44:17 1   255 1   0
    4   2017-11-01 11:00:28 1   255 1   0
   14   2017-11-01 11:00:59 1   255 1   0
    5   2017-11-01 11:24:50 1   255 1   0
    9   2017-11-01 12:46:32 1   255 1   0
    6   2017-11-01 12:58:24 1   255 1   0
   11   2017-11-01 13:00:18 1   255 1   0
    1   2017-11-01 13:00:28 1   255 1   0
    2   2017-11-01 16:06:14 1   255 1   0
    2   2017-11-01 16:06:24 1   255 1   0
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question.

Comment: I'm curious, why didn't you include a `TimeOut` column? How would you know if an employee timed out?

Comment: Are you saying that `TimeIn` isn't actually `TimeIn`?  It's actually `TimeCardSwiped` or something?  Then, the first "swipe" is *implicitly* `In` and the next "swipe" is *implicitly* `out`?  If so, is it ***ever*** possible to get in or out without "swiping"?  *(Such as getting a temporary pass and a security guard buzzing them through?)*  And I assume some people sometimes "swipe in" before midnight and then "swipe out" the next day? *(A night shift)*.  Please think through all similar occurrences and give a *very* specific description of all eventualities.

Comment: We get the data from fingerprint machine like this they have no separate column for TimeIn and TimeOut. So have an only single column by which we have to find out time like this ....if first entry its mean TimeIn and the second entry is TimeOut and third is TimeIn and Fourth are TimeOut and so on....for one employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow there is no in and out you can only assume first input as IN while next as Out.

you can inner join to next value to get time diff than filtering only odd value(even will be time out)

```
select a.row, a.empid, timestampdiff(second,a.timein, ifnull(b.timeout,date_add(date(a.timein) , interval 1 day))) timeinsec from 
(SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=o.empid,@row_num+1,1) AS Row,
    empid ,timein,       
   @prev_value := o.empid
FROM Table1 o,
  (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
  (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
 ORDER BY o.empid,timein asc
 ) a 

 join

 (SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value2=o.empid,@row_num+1,1) AS Row,
    empid ,timein as timeout,       
   @prev_value2 := o.empid
  FROM Table1 o,
  (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
  (SELECT @prev_value2 := '') y
  ORDER BY o.empid,timein asc) b
 on a.empid=b.empid and a.row=b.row-1
 where mod(a.row,2)=1
```

## Edit

1. Datediff changed to timestampdiff
2. null situation handled

Comment: Vishal its works, but when there is no out on that day by mistake then result is getting wrong ie. 0.

Comment: that is logically True. If someone does not check out then how will you calculate its time in office? however, there is a workaround you can set any fixed time of day if its null.

Comment: Will you add 12:00 am as a fixed time in your SQL query?

Comment: Absolutely perfect. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(HOUR(TimeIn))  FROM table_biometric  group by DATE(TimeIn),Employee_id
```

using the query you will obtain the total hour worked by day for each employee

and after you can if you want sum the number of hours of all day by a function

finally you can use the datetime function for other help

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: We work on your query we got wrong hours. If an employee "in" he scans a thumb then when "out" he again scan, Date time is entered in only one column. Secondly, Employee again scans his finger for entry and after some hours out with a finger scan. It means we have to calculate hours for two pairs of in-out entry in single day

Comment: is there a colum to differentiate with datetime "in" and "out"

Comment: we get two entry one for IN and Other is OUT

Comment: 1   2017-11-01 05:56:24          1   2017-11-01 13:00:28 1

Comment: EmpID   DateTime
 13       2017-10-31 05:15:11 
 13       2017-10-31 13:45:27
 13       2017-10-31 23:15:11 
 13       2017-10-31 23:45:27
Employee 13 has four records we considered it as First is IN second is Out calculate hours in this period. Then Third is IN and Four is Out we calculate hours in this period.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know your table columns. Would be nice to have the result of the `describe your_table_name` query.

But you can adapt this query for your needs:

```
SELECT
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(t1.your_datetime_column_name))), "%h:%i") AS diff

from table t1
LEFT join table t2
on  t1.primary_key_column_name != t2.primary_key_column_name
  WHERE t1.primary_key_column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You have not mentioned the EmployeeID column.

Comment: I believed thats your `primary_key_column_name`. Since I don't know your columns names ...